# Looping through SQL table and appending extra dictionaries to JSON output using Pyodbc

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a SQL table that I am converting to a JSON object that has higher level information such as Service Request Number, Address, lat/lng, etc.

The nested dictionaries will always be information pertinent to the higher level dictionaries such as the commodity type i.e. (e-waste), item type i.e. (microwave), count of items collected i.e. (2).

I have two keys which are required so that the server I am sending the JSON to accepts the request.

My question is, how do I successfully loop through the lower level information in my table and append these dictionaries to my higher level dictionary? There can also be up 10 of these dictionaries.  One SRNumber has one commodity type.

I am able to achieve my results through hardcoding as I have done below, but my inner dictionaries are dynamic i.e. `ListofLA311ElectronicWaste` can easily be `ListofLA311BulkyItems` with an associated inner dictionary for it.

My Current Output:

```
{
        "MetaData": {}, 
        "SRData": {
            "ListOfLa311ElectronicWaste": {
                "La311ElectronicWaste": [
                    {
                        "DriverFirstName": "Bob", 
                        "DriverLastName": "Williams", 
                        "ItemCount": "2", 
                        "Type": "Electronic Waste"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            "ReasonCode": "", 
            "ResolutionCode": "", 
            "SRNumber": "1-17991171"
        }
    }
]
```

Code:

```
import pyodbc
import json
import collections
import requests
import time
import logging
import httplib
import datetime
import logging
import logging.handlers



results = []
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    result = dict(zip(columns, row))
    SRNumber =  result['SRNumber']
    rescode = result ['ResolutionCode']
    results.append({'MetaData': {}, 'SRData': {'SRNumber':SRNumber,'ReasonCode':"",'ResolutionCode': rescode, ""'ListOfLa311ElectronicWaste' : {"La311ElectronicWaste" : [{'ItemCount': '2', 'Type': "Electronic Waste", 'DriverFirstName': "Bob", "DriverLastName": "Williams" }]}}})
    print json.dumps(results, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Desired Output;

```
{
    "MetaData": {},
    "SRData": {
        "ListOfLa311ElectronicWaste": {
            "La311ElectronicWaste": [
                {
                    "DriverFirstName": "aDriverFirst",
                    "DriverLastName": "aDriverLast",
                    "ItemCount": "3",
                    "ElectronicWestType": " Microwave",
                    "Type": "Electronic Waste"
                },
                {
                    "DriverFirstName": "aDriverFirst",
                    "DriverLastName": "aDriverLast",
                    "ItemCount": " 10",
                    "ElectronicWasteType": "Television",
                    "Type": "Electronic Waste",
                    "Name": "c2d66d96-2439-4486-b4f0-5377b084cdff"
                },
                {
                    "DriverFirstName": "aDriverFirst",
                    "DriverLastName": "aDriverLast",
                    "ItemCount": " 2",
                    "ElectronicWasteType": "Cell Phone",
                    "Type": "Electronic Waste",
                    "Name": "c2d66d96-2439-4486-b4f0-5377b084cdff"
                },
                {
                    "DriverFirstName": "aDriverFirst",
                    "DriverLastName": "aDriverLast",
                    "ItemCount": " 7",
                    "ElectronicWasteType": "Monitors",
                    "Type": "Electronic Waste",
                    "Name": "c2d66d96-2439-4486-b4f0-5377b084cdff"
                },
                {
                    "DriverFirstName": "aDriverFirst",
                    "DriverLastName": "aDriverLast",
                    "ItemCount": " 1",
                    "ElectronicWasteType": "Keyboards",
                    "Type": "Electronic Waste",
                    "Name": "c2d66d96-2439-4486-b4f0-5377b084cdff"
                },
                {
                    "DriverFirstName": "aDriverFirst",
                    "DriverLastName": "aDriverLast",
                    "ItemCount": " 1",
                    "ElectronicWasteType": "ac adapter",
                    "Type": "Electronic Waste",
                    "Name": "c2d66d96-2439-4486-b4f0-5377b084cdff"
                },
                {
                    "DriverFirstName": "aDriverFirst",
                    "DriverLastName": "aDriverLast",
                    "ItemCount": " 1",
                    "ElectronicWasteType": "headphones",
                    "Type": "Electronic Waste",
                    "Name": "c2d66d96-2439-4486-b4f0-5377b084cdff"
                },
                {
                    "DriverFirstName": "aDriverFirst",
                    "DriverLastName": "aDriverLast",
                    "ItemCount": " 1",
                    "ElectronicWasteType": "generator",
                    "Type": "Electronic Waste",
                    "Name": "c2d66d96-2439-4486-b4f0-5377b084cdff"
                },
                {
                    "DriverFirstName": "aDriverFirst",
                    "DriverLastName": "aDriverLast",
                    "ItemCount": " 1",
                    "ElectronicWasteType": "electric stapler",
                    "Type": "Electronic Waste",
                    "Name": "c2d66d96-2439-4486-b4f0-5377b084cdff"
                },
                {
                    "DriverFirstName": "aDriverFirst",
                    "DriverLastName": "aDriverLast",
                    "ItemCount": " 1",
                    "ElectronicWasteType": "laptop",
                    "Type": "Electronic Waste",
                    "Name": "c2d66d96-2439-4486-b4f0-5377b084cdff"
                },
                {
                    "DriverFirstName": "aDriverFirst",
                    "DriverLastName": "aDriverLast",
                    "ItemCount": " 1",
                    "ElectronicWasteType": "battery",
                    "Type": "Electronic Waste",
                    "Name": "c2d66d96-2439-4486-b4f0-5377b084cdff"
                }
            ]
        },
        "ReasonCode": "",
        "ResolutionCode": "",
        "SRNumber": "1-17991171"
    }
}
```

Comment: might I make a suggestion?  Can you get rid of all the cursor-y stuff from your example code?  I realize that it is important to you, but it doesn't affect your json-building requirements all that much and you have it well under control.  If you instead boiled it down to a list of dictionaries that simulate your SRNumber and rescode, and then a metadata lookup mock dictionary, we'd be much easier off to help you.  Your requirements don't look very hard to meet.  Illustrate this in your sample:  *There can also be up 10 of these dictionaries.*

Comment: @JLPeyret pelase see edits.

Answer (score 1):

Not saying it'll fit your requirements perfectly, but it should get you started.

Using a lot of **my_dictionary.get(key,default)** with acceptable missing default values to look things up in the metadata's dictionaries will make your code more robust.  And you can also conditionally skip stuff when there is no data to be found.

One more thing:  there are some requirements to valid json data.  Be cautious of embedded **"** string delimiters for example.  [JSON linter online](http://jsonlint.com/) can be helpful there.  Also, Python json.dumps is not as robust as some other Python json encoders libraries, so you may want to look for alternatives if the online parsers are OK, but your json.dumps is not.

```
import json 

#create a mockup of your cursor data...
SRNumber_17991171 = "1-17991171"

li_simulate_cursor=[
    dict(ResolutionCode="", SRNumber=SRNumber_17991171)
]

#create a mockup of what the higher order data looks like
#http://jsonlint.com/ can be a help...

s17991171 = """{
                "name" : "ListOfLa311ElectronicWaste",
                "driverlist": 
                        [
                    {
                        "DriverFirstName": "aDriverFirst",
                        "DriverLastName": "aDriverLast",
                        "ItemCount": "3",
                        "ElectronicWestType": " Microwave",
                        "Type": "Electronic Waste"
                    },
                    {
                        "DriverFirstName": "aDriverFirst",
                        "DriverLastName": "aDriverLast",
                        "ItemCount": " 10",
                        "ElectronicWasteType": "Television",
                        "Type": "Electronic Waste",
                        "Name": "c2d66d96-2439-4486-b4f0-5377b084cdff"
                    }          
                    ]
                }
"""

#this is totally bogus, a mockup, but you 
di_lookup_meta = {"1-17991171": json.loads(s17991171)}


#ok, now all done with the prep, let's proceed
results = []
for row in li_simulate_cursor:
    result = row
    SRNumber =  result['SRNumber']
    rescode = result ['ResolutionCode']

    try:
        #lookup your meta for the the cursor results
        meta = di_lookup_meta.get(SRNumber,"")

        #transform your higher order data to your desired output format
        name = meta.get("name")
        driverlist = meta.get("driverlist")
        MetaData = meta.get("MetaData", {})

        di_meta = {name:driverlist}

    except KeyError, e:
        print "not found:%s in %s" % (SRNumber, di_lookup_meta.keys())
        raise


    di_json = dict(
        MetaData = MetaData,
        SRData = dict(SRNumber=SRNumber,ResolutionCode=rescode),
        )

    #embedding your higher order
    di_json.update(di_meta)

    results.append(di_json)

    # results.append({'MetaData': {}, 'SRData': {'SRNumber':SRNumber,'ReasonCode':"",'ResolutionCode': rescode, ""'ListOfLa311ElectronicWaste' : {"La311ElectronicWaste" : [{'ItemCount': '2', 'Type': "Electronic Waste", 'DriverFirstName': "Bob", "DriverLastName": "Williams" }]}}})

print json.dumps(results, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

output:

```
[
    {
        "ListOfLa311ElectronicWaste": [
            {
                "DriverFirstName": "aDriverFirst", 
                "DriverLastName": "aDriverLast", 
                "ElectronicWestType": " Microwave", 
                "ItemCount": "3", 
                "Type": "Electronic Waste"
            }, 
            {
                "DriverFirstName": "aDriverFirst", 
                "DriverLastName": "aDriverLast", 
                "ElectronicWasteType": "Television", 
                "ItemCount": " 10", 
                "Name": "c2d66d96-2439-4486-b4f0-5377b084cdff", 
                "Type": "Electronic Waste"
            }
        ], 
        "MetaData": {}, 
        "SRData": {
            "ResolutionCode": "", 
            "SRNumber": "1-17991171"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: This is a good start, thank you @JLPeyret, however my `MetaData` and `SRData` tags should be reordered so they are above the commodity tags.  How can this be done?

Comment: Python dicts are not ordered so you won't get that.   The json is valid regardless.  Now, if you really do need for formatting/human readability, then check if **collections.OrderedDict** s can help you out with that (I dunno).  But they are a bit trickier than regular dictionaries to work with.  Or again, maybe a cleverer encoder than json.dump.

Comment: Ordered dicts do the trick for json.dump, but note that your own debugging code is json.dumps(results, **sort_keys=True**, indent=4)